Thread hook function
I have two threads f1() and f2(), how can I make a function say g() called every time a thread is awakened to run? For example before thread f1() starts g() is called and returned and f1() runs, then when f2() is activated and f1() is put to sleep, g() is called before f2() runs, and so on…regardless whether the threads run concurrently or in parallel, I’m just interested in adding a hook function g at the thread activation point!
Thanks.

You could easily do it with coöperative multithreading.  Not sure how you'd do that with preëmptive multithreading — because of the preëmptive part.

If you are using a RTOS for an embedded device, you would typically have access to the source code of the thread scheduler and could program a hook there. If you are using a regular OS like Linux, Windows or macOS, I guess you are out of luck.

Learn about std::mutex, std::unique_lock and std::condition_variable (last one despite its name is more of an interthread signal). You can then use the condition variable to signal you entered a thread (and setting some state) and other code can wakeup on that

You can ask for callbacks when threads are created and destroyed. I'm not aware of any infrastructure that would allow you to install a callback whenever a thread gets scheduled to run.

@prapin, mentioning Linux and saying you can't customize it to your needs is surprising. The kernel and everything around it is open source, so you absolutely can. Anyhow, this question is tagged with "winapi", which implies MS Windows.

What thread would that hook run in? How would you like this to behave when there are many threads? I can't even envision clearly how such a hook would behave, and that's the catch: I have a feeling that you have a so-called "XY Problem", i.e. that you're asking the wrong question.

Ok so it’s not doable at the api level, that’s what I was thinking.

@OhWizz3 no, it's not doable using winapi. But out of curiosity: what is the use case ? Why do you actually need this ?

You can try fibers which allow manual scheduling?

As a conclusion, the transfer between the two states should be transparent when programming and winapi also doesn't support such function currently. You already know that it’s not doable at the api level.
